# Create Css Box with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a css box with bootstrap. Please check it here
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvg6dtxa/3)

- the padding box why the margin-top not effect !
- the inputs must be in the same align but its not why !

Here My HTML

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 CssBox">
                <div class="MargingBox">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="MarginTop" placeholder="-">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="MarginRight" placeholder="-">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="MarginBottom" placeholder="-">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="MarginLeft" placeholder="-">
                    <div class="BorderBox">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="BorderTop" placeholder="-">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="BorderRight" placeholder="-">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="BorderBottom" placeholder="-">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="BorderLeft" placeholder="-">
                        <div class="PaddingBox">
                        <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="PaddingTop" placeholder="-">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PaddingRight" placeholder="-">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PaddingBottom" placeholder="-">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PaddingLeft" placeholder="-">-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: for the **he padding box why the margin-top not effect !** that i can say is you need to apply **position:relative** that will work for you

Answer (score 2):

you can using `float:left` OR `display: inline-block;` to set top margin.

```css
.CssBox .MargingBox {
 position: relative;
 border: 1px dashed #CCC;
 height: 250px;
 
}
.CssBox .BorderBox {
 background-color: #e3e7ed;
    float: left;
    height: 166px;
    margin: 44px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
 
}
.CssBox .PaddingBox {

 background-color: #ff0000;
    float: left;
    height: 86px;
    margin: 44px;
    width: calc(100% - 90px);
 
}
.CssBox input {
 width: 30px !important;
 height: 25px;
 position: absolute;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 0;
}
.CssBox .MargingBox input#MarginTop ,
.CssBox .BorderBox input#BorderTop ,
.CssBox .PaddingBox input#PaddingTop {
 left: 45%;
 top: 12px;
 
}
.CssBox .MargingBox input#MarginRight , 
.CssBox .BorderBox input#BorderRight ,
.CssBox .PaddingBox input#PaddingRight{
 top: 50%;
 right: 8px;
 
}
.CssBox .MargingBox input#MarginBottom, 
.CssBox .BorderBox input#BorderBottom ,
.CssBox .PaddingBox input#PaddingBottom{
 left: 46%;
 bottom: 6px;
}
.CssBox .MargingBox input#MarginLeft,
.CssBox .BorderBox input#BorderLeft ,
.CssBox .PaddingBox input#PaddingLeft{
 top: 46%;
 left: 8px;

}
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 CssBox">
     <div class="MargingBox">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="MarginTop" placeholder="-">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="MarginRight" placeholder="-">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="MarginBottom" placeholder="-">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="MarginLeft" placeholder="-">
      <div class="BorderBox">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="BorderTop" placeholder="-">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="BorderRight" placeholder="-">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="BorderBottom" placeholder="-">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="BorderLeft" placeholder="-">
       <div class="PaddingBox">
       <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="PaddingTop" placeholder="-">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PaddingRight" placeholder="-">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PaddingBottom" placeholder="-">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PaddingLeft" placeholder="-">-->
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div> 
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

for your padding box here is the one i tried and worked

> and for the input that are not been aligned is due to that you have
>   provided respective top,left,right,bottoms to both the boxes' inputs
>   so that they are taking the both's respective positions so might work
>   on that

```css
.CssBox .PaddingBox {
    position:relative;
    top:25%;
 margin: 44px;
 height:86px;
 background-color: red;
}
```

check out the jsfiddle

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uvg6dtxa/6/)**

Comment: nice answer , can you find answer for this problem the inputs be align 

http://jsfiddle.net/uvg6dtxa/9/